# Hard disc not recognized by Windows, but recognized in BIOS + Linux

Tags: linux, windows-10, hard-drive

I have this strange problem that I don't know how to resolve after hours of researching.

I have 2 M2 PCie SSDs, A & B.

A is a 240GB SSD, exclusively used for my Windows 10.

B is a 1TB SSD, and I have a bunch of data on it. After a while, I partitioned B and installed Linux on it. I ran out of size on my Linux root partition, so I booted into GParted, moved and resized partitions, and eventually...broke my Linux. After that, my Windows stopped seeing my 1TB SSD altogether (not even in Disc Management).

I can still see the disc in BIOS, I installed a brand new Linux system onto the disc and boots into the Linux system, but for some reason, my Windows just fails to recognize the disc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What file system is the disk using at this point since you reinstalled Linux on it?

Comment: the disc is now having 5 partitions like this:

`nvme0n1
├─nvme0n1p1
├─nvme0n1p2 ntfs
├─nvme0n1p3 ext4
├─nvme0n1p4 swap
└─nvme0n1p5 ext4`

Comment: Windows can't see or read ext4 without adding driver support for that filesystem.  Have you tried going into windows disk management and seeing what partitions it is able to see and or mount?

Comment: I have another drive, which is in ext4 and i use it exclusively to store backups for my linux system. Windows CAN'T access it, but it still shows up in disc management. Only this particular drive is not shown at all.

Comment: Anything interesting in Device Manager?

Comment: Device Manager shows no sign of that disc either. It was still fine before I tried to resized the partitions and broke my linux...